# How to stop D3.js from creating infinite areas from linear polygons

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson, tilestache

I'm trying to draw topojson features with D3, they are generated by TileStache from a PostGIS database. Small triangular polygons tend to simplify into "lines": the 3 points are on a straight line. If the TopoJSON goes like this the polygon is drawn as a line:

```
"arcs":[[[609,278],[-1,-1],[-1,-1],[2,2]]]
```

However if the TopoJSON goes like this:

```
"arcs":[[[609,278],[-2,-2],[1,1],[1,1]]]}
```

An infinite area with a 'line shaped' hole is drawn, messing up the map. How can I stop D3 from creating infinite areas when the feature is line-shaped?

You can see the effect of the two styles of TopoJSON here:
http://research.geodan.nl/sites/vectortiling/test/faultytile.html

The are greater effect of these infinite features is visible here: http://research.geodan.nl/sites/vectortiling/

Comment: Try array.reverse(), the winding order matters in D3 but it doesn't always matter in other applications.

Comment: As the comment on the D3 documentation suggested, can't you use [ST_ForceRHR](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) at the source (PostGIS) DB? Or does the problem occur after processing with TileStache?

Comment: The topojson is produced by TileStache, using its Goodies/VecTiles/topojson.py provider. It retrieves the features as WKB  and encodes those in topojson. I noticed that it turns the coordinates in differential integers and it is very well possible that with that action the perfectly clockwise triangular polygon is turned into the above mentioned line-polygon. So there is hardly a way to solve it in PostGIS I'm afraid.

Comment: As I suspected, one level zoomed in the topojson is a triangle: `[194,555],[-5,-5],[2,4],[3,1]` if you zoom out the polygon will shrink and these last three values will be halved: `[-2.5,-2.5],[1,2],[3,1]` however since topojson works with integers everything needs to be rounded off. Depending on the original values the two possible results are `[-2,-2],[1,1],[1,1]` and `[-2,-2],[1,2],[1,0]`. As such the faulty topojson is the result of simplifying a perfectly valid polygon and follows the right hand rule, albeit for large values of 1. So I believe D3 is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bug in D3 see: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2025 I've created a basic fix by checking if the polygon has an area of zero and if so, return false at the pointInPolygon function. Jason and Mike are working on it, so I hope at some point there will be a D3 release which doesn't create infinite polygons :)